# How to plot odd even square wave using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below python codes so as to generates a square wave at one specific position. For Eg: you enter 0, the signal is high[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ivso.png) only between 0 and 1[Odd=High]. You enter 1, the output is high[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ivso.png) only between 1 and 2 [Even = High]. How do you extend the below python codes so as to generate odd or even square wave throughout the time span rather that at a single position. Here I am facing problem with 2*n+1 formula.Could anyone help me in this?

Please refer the image below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SquareWave(n):
    xmin=0;
    xmax=10;

    ymin=-2;
    ymax=2;

    Nx=1000;
    offset=1;

    x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Nx);
    y=np.sign(x+n)*offset;

    y[(x<n)]=0;
    y[(x>n+1)]=0;

    plt.plot(x, y);
    plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]);
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

[image: Odd Wave]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `;`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SquareWave(n,xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=-2,Nx=1000,ymax=2,offset=1):

    x=np.sort(np.concatenate([np.arange(xmin, xmax)-1E-6,np.arange(xmin, xmax)+1E-6])) 
    #You can use np.linspace(xmin,xmax,Nx) if you want the intermediate points

    y=np.array(x+n+offset,dtype=int)%2


    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong with `;`? You don't say.